# Returning a dynamically allocated array of structures from a function in C?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct, hashtable

```
typedef struct {
    List *table;
    unsigned int size;
} HashTable;

typedef struct node {
    Data data;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;

struct listptrs {
    NODE *tail;
    NODE *head;
    NODE *prev;
    NODE *current;
};

typedef struct listptrs List;

HashTable createHashTable(unsigned int size) {
    //HashTable htable = { 0 };
    //return htable;

    int i;
    HashTable *htable = NULL;
    htable = malloc(sizeof(HashTable) * size);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        htable[i].table = malloc(sizeof(List));
        htable[i].table->current = NULL;
        htable[i].table->head = NULL;
        htable[i].table->prev = NULL;
        htable[i].table->tail = NULL;
        htable[i].size = size;
    }
    return *htable;//???
}
```

Then in main:

```
HashTable htable = createHashTable(tableSize);
```

`htable` doesn't act like an array at all. Any ideas how to solve it without changing any return value from the function and arguments for functions? This is part of a school assignment and only the contents of the function `createHashTable` may be changed. The rest of the program is not here because it isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: Maybe you should return a *pointer* to `HashTable` from the function? Right now you're returning only the first element in the array you have created (and have a memory leak). Or change the type-alias `HashTable` to be a pointer (which I really don't recommend).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You maybe want this:

```
HashTable *createHashTable(unsigned int size)
{
    //HashTable htable = { 0 };
    //return htable;

    int i;
    HashTable* htable = NULL;
    htable = malloc(sizeof(HashTable)* size);
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        htable[i].table = malloc(sizeof(List));
        htable[i].table->current = NULL;
        htable[i].table->head = NULL;
        htable[i].table->prev = NULL;
        htable[i].table->tail = NULL;
        htable[i].size = size;
    }

    return htable;
}
```

As you allocate the array dynamically, you can simply return the newly allocated pointer. Returning a `HashTable` as you were trying doesn't make senses, because this would allow you to return one single `HashTable`, but you want to return a whole array of `HashTable`s.

**Usage:**

Instead of:

```
HashTable htable = createHashTable(tableSize);
```

You need this:

```
HashTable *htable = createHashTable(100);
...
... // when done you need to delete the hashtable
deleteHashTable(htable);
```

The `deleteHashTable` is yet to be written, It essentially needs to `free` the `table` pointer and to `free` the table itself.

Now if you really are allowed to change only the contents of the `createHashTable` function but not the function signature, then your question doesn't make sense because with the function signature `HashTable createHashTable(unsigned int size)` you can only return *one* `HashTable` but not an array of `HashTable`s.

But then maybe you actually want this:

```
HashTable createHashTable(unsigned int size)
{
    HashTable htable = { 0 };

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        htable[i].table = malloc(sizeof(List));
        htable[i].table->current = NULL;
        htable[i].table->head = NULL;
        htable[i].table->prev = NULL;
        htable[i].table->tail = NULL;
        htable[i].size = size;
    }

    return htable;
}
```

With this second solution, you still need to write the function that deletes the hash table.

Comment: Allocating an array of `HashTable` does not really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The hash table itself isn't supposed to "behave like an array", and this:

```
return *htable;
```

makes no sense, it returns the first element from your array of *hash tables*.

You're not supposed to create an array of hash tables though, you're supposed to create *a single hash table*, which might *contain* an array (that's the table). It also has a size variable for instance, so there's more than the array itself to the hash table.

You should do

```
htable = malloc(sizeof *htable);
```

to allocate a single instance, then initialize that as needed and return it.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion here: `createHashTable()` is not supposed to allocate an array of hash tables, but a `HashTable` structure with an initial size for its embedded `table` member.

Furthermore, it is non standard practice to return the structure by value. You should instead return the pointer to the allocated `HashTable` or possibly take a pointer to `HashTable` structure allocated dynamically or statically by the caller and initialize that.

Here is a modified version of the code for this approach:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    List *table;
    unsigned int size;
} HashTable;

typedef struct node {
    Data data;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;

struct listptrs {
    NODE *tail;
    NODE *head;
    NODE *prev;
    NODE *current;
};

typedef struct listptrs List;

HashTable *createHashTable(unsigned int size) {
    HashTable *htable = malloc(sizeof(*htable));

    if (htable == NULL) 
        return NULL;
    }
    htable->size = size;
    htable->table = NULL;
    if (size == 0) {
        return htable;
    }
    htable->table = malloc(sizeof(*htable->table) * size);
    if (htable->table == NULL) {
        free(htable);
        return NULL;
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        htable->table[i].head = NULL;
        htable->table[i].tail = NULL;
        htable->table[i].prev = NULL;
        htable->table[i].current = NULL;
    }
    return htable;
}
```

Calling from `main()`:

```
HashTable *htable = createHashTable(100);
```